# Ansible - modify variable.stdout subfield

Tags: ansible

I have this output from an ansible shell task, it's a json:

```
stdout: {
  "override_attributes": {
    "prod": {
      "hosts": [
        "10.100.0.150",
        "10.100.0.151"
]
}}}
```

I want to modify the IPs something like this:

```
set_fact: variable.stdout.override_attributes.prod.hosts=groups['GROUP_A']
```

And after that I would like to see the full json modified variable.stdout

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is an ugly solution with `combine` filter:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    stdout: {
      "override_attributes": {
        "prod": {
          "hosts": [
            "10.100.0.150",
            "10.100.0.151"
           ],
          "users": [
            "user1",
            "user2"
          ]
    }}}
    new_hosts:
      - host_name1
      - host_name2
  tasks:
    # original stdout
    - debug: var=stdout
    # update override_attributes.prod.hosts with new_hosts
    - set_fact:
        stdout: "{{stdout | combine({\"override_attributes\":{\"prod\":{\"hosts\":new_hosts} } }, recursive=True )}}"
    # updated stdout, users list unchanged
    - debug: var=stdout
```

Comment: Instead of new_hosts var if I try with groups['some_group'] I get: "msg": "|combine expects dictionaries, got u''"}

Comment: @ady8531 check that "some_group" is really there. Try `groups['all']` first to ensure that everything works. I use ansible 2.1

Comment: I replaced your new_hosts with: "groups['EH']|map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_eth1','ipv4', 'address']) | list" and it's ok but I have another issue: at the debug it looks ok but if I want to put the contents of stdout into a file with blockinfile or echo {{ stdout }} redirect into file, it puts everything into one line. I also tried with filter to_json or to_nice_json and got the same result (even worse with some as they strip the quotation marks)

Comment: @ady8531 it seems there are some quirks with printing json, but if you append some other character (e.g. newline) to the content, everything begins to work – `block: "\n{{ stdout | to_nice_json }}"`